# Bind data of one component to another component without parent child relationship in angular 8

Tags: angular8

I have Home service which is calling the user's details API using httpClient and then I have imported that service in my Home component and subscribe that service in my Home Component which gives me the details of that user i.e `firstname`. and I have stored that first name into the variable 'firstname'

Now i have another component header.component.html I want to display that `firstname` from home component to this header componenent

Home component belongs to the dashboard module and header component is in the app module and there is no direct or parent child relationship between these component

Help me that how I can bind the `firstname` of the home component to header component

Below is the code of my home.component.ts where I have stored the value of `firstname` into the variable for binding into header component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeService } from '../../_service/home.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  users : []
  firstname ;  
   lastname ;
  constructor(private homeservice: HomeService) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.homeservice.getuser()
    .subscribe(
      res =>{
        this.users= res.userDetails;
        this.firstname = this.users['first_name'];
        this.lastname = this.users['last_name'];
        console.log(this.users);
        console.log(this.firstname)
      }
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you considered adding a `SharedModule` in which to provide the `HomeService` and import that module in both `AppModule` and `DashboardModule`? This way you could use the service in both modules. https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#shared-feature-module

Comment: is there any way to bind the value of firstname name variable to header.component.html directly without using or calling service for both components seprately. i actually wants to call service just once in home component and then bind the firstname to the header component .